# Mysql, new regional-disks based HA upgrade done. Can I disable GTIDs now?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I've just upgraded my Cloud SQL instance (Mysql) to use the new, regional-disks based replication, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha#ha-existing

Can GTIDs (finally) be disabled now in order to execute 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE' within transactions? Or are they still needed for backups?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/0-lti-H3crE
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-mode-change-online-disable-gtids.html

Comment: I guess that it's still needed as they are attached with the binary logs and the binary logs are needed for high availability on CloudSQL. Also, in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features#differences) states clearly that it's not a supported operation to use for example 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE' statements inside transactions.

Comment: Yeah, though their new 'HA approach' effectively does not use the classic master-slave replication mechanism. No data is ever sent to the slave. Though, I gather, GTIDs are still needed for the (optional) point-in-time recovery and, indeed, if I try to disable binary logging while having HA on the cloud interface returns an error. I guess I'm stuck till they upgrade to Mysql 8.0.13 or allow GTIDs to be turned off, both of which could take ages...

Comment: You can't have HA without binary logs. The UI returns an error for exactly that reason. I know that isn't well explained the provided message, but that's the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching regarding your question, you can't have High Availability, without binary logs.

Searching also for requests of disabling the GTIDs, this is not possible right, since they are related to binary logs and also in order to do that you need to have SUPER privileges.

To sum up, this is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features#differences) in the differences of CLOUDSQL and standard MySQL that you are not able to create Temporary table and other statements.

Bear in mind that you can set up [MySQL on Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql) and then you will be able to have SUPER USER privileges.

Also FYI: There was a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/72513647) about it with an answer.